# spring web mvc, webapplicationconfig currentsession integration

Tags: spring, hibernate

İ developed a web application using spring and hibernate. This is pretty huge app and i have to get some services from outside of controllers as well. For this i used xmlclasspathcontext to get beans at the same time.

Currently i am using threadlocal and opensession. So far i do not have problem except reading old data when update somethings. İ know this happens because of threadlocal keep current session.

What i want to learn is, İF i remove threadlocal and use öpensession and close session is it a good approach?
Because i cant use getcurrentsession with controllers and getbeans at the same time. İam getting no session found err at the xmXML get bean side. Is there a way to get getcurrentsession at both side? Or do i haveto use open and close session approach? What İF i do not close each opwnsession?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yupsoft.grid" /> 
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grid" />
        <property name="username" value="myuser" />
        <property name="password" value="mypass" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />      
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.yupsoft.yupsoft.model.LanguageTextParameter</value>
                <value>com.yupsoft.yupsoft.model.LoginHistory</value>
                <value>com.yupsoft.yupsoft.model.Session</value>
                <value>com.yupsoft.yupsoft.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <!--
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                 --> 

                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>

                <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1;</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">8</prop>                
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

This is Controller class that I am getting requests

```
@Controller
```

public class UserController {

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@Autowired
private LoginHistoryService loginHistoryService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/loginAttempt", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String loginAttempt(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    User user = userService.getByUserNameAndPassword(userName, password);
    if (user != null) {
        if (user.isActive()) {
            LoginHistory loginHistory = new LoginHistory();
            loginHistory.setCreated(new Date());
            loginHistory.setIpAddress(request.getRemoteAddr());
            loginHistory.setSessionId(request.getSession().getId());
            loginHistory.setAccountVerified(Boolean.TRUE);
            loginHistory.setUser(user);
            boolean loginHistoryCreated = loginHistoryService.create(loginHistory);
            if (loginHistoryCreated) {
        return "ok";                
            } else {
                //Error
                return "err";
            }
        } else {
            return "err";
        }
    } 

    return "ok";
}
```

}

This is Service layer

```
@Service("loginHistoryService")
```

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public class LoginHistoryServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl implements LoginHistoryService {

```
@Autowired
private LoginHistoryDAO loginHistoryDAO;

public LoginHistoryDAO getLoginHistoryDAO() {
    return loginHistoryDAO;
}

public void setLoginHistoryDAO(LoginHistoryDAO loginHistoryDAO) {
    this.loginHistoryDAO = loginHistoryDAO;
    setGenericDAO(loginHistoryDAO);
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
@Override
public boolean create(LoginHistory obj) {
    return loginHistoryDAO.create(obj);
}
```

This part is DAO layer

```
@Repository("loginHistoryDAO")
```

public class LoginHistoryDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl implements LoginHistoryDAO {

```
@Autowired
private SessionDAO sessionDAO;

@Override
public boolean create(LoginHistory obj) {        
    try {
        //beginTransaction();
        save(obj);
        if (obj.isAccountVerified()) {
            Session s = new Session();
            s.setActive(Boolean.TRUE);
            s.setIpAddress(obj.getIpAddress());
            s.setCreated(new Date());
            s.setSessionId(obj.getSessionId());
            s.setUser(obj.getUser());
            sessionDAO.save(s);
        }
        //commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

And last part is generic part

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

@Repository
public abstract class GenericDAOImpl implements GenericDAO {

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private final Class<T> persistentClass;

public GenericDAOImpl() {
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
    return persistentClass;
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public Session getCurrentSession() throws HibernateException {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Override
public Transaction beginTransaction() {
    return getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
}

@Override
public void commitTransaction() {
    getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
```

I am trying to replace openSession() to getCurrentSession()
and I require to control beginTransaction() and tx.commit(). Because I have more than one entity to save or update at the same time. So, I need to wrap those intities in a transaction, be sure all done or all did not done.

When I use getCurrentSession() I am getting this error;

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.virdyn.grid.core.system.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:660)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:412)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.virdyn.grid.controller.UserController.loginAttempt(UserController.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:100)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    ... 43 more

I want to cancel ThreadLocal and use getCurrentSession.
What is wrong in here Or do you have other purposes. In fact I can use opensession() and closeSession for any method in all dao's. If I do that is it to slow my system?
I am waiting solutions thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be using a different application context in the first place, fix that and your issues will be solved.

Comment: Also welcome to stack overflow, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then update your question accordingly (add some code and configuration the least).

Comment: If i remove classpathxmlapplicationcontext, how can i get some services from outside of controllers? I have to reach many service beans from inside other classes

Comment: You can inject them into every managed bean not only controllers...

Comment: İ removed classpathxmlapplicationcontext to bridge for services and it workef fine. Currently i can get any service from anywhere. Bút now i have another problem. Because of i changed to getcurrentsession autocommit not disabling and i am getting transaction not successfuly started error. Why autocommit false does not work?

Comment: auto-commit is off by default when you use transactions, else the transaction would be pretty useless. Also you shouldn't be getting beans (if yu still do that) you should use dependency injection instead. Also when using `getCurrentSession` you should have setup springs transaction management correctly (and don't mess around with `current_session_context` property on the `SessionFactory`). For some reason I get the feeling you are trying/configuring too much and work against the framework instead of with the framework.

Comment: I am using springcontextbridgeservices and ın it services are autowired. Bút main problem is when i try to update data which request comes from controllers postconstruct method with autowired service i am getting this transaction error. Normally all services dependency injected. Bút i could find why autocommit does not work. If i switch to open session everything works properly. Bút isnt it better tp use getcurrent session? İ am using MySQL is it problem?

Comment: Why are you using that service you don't need it... Also transactions don't work in a `@PostConstruct` method as proxies might not be created at that point.

Comment: I have to make some queries from inside another classes and i need to get those services. And none of transactions work, not only ın postconstruct. For instance a standard create or update request fails. In this system i have about 70 entity to manage. i have lots of algoalgoritma to get lists, query some. So i can not do everything ın services only. And i have to use autocommit false and manually manually commit because i have to update more than öne entity at the same time. So i cant use autocommit türü. Bút sistem not allow me to make autocommit false.  how can i disable autocommit?

Comment: What are those other classes, you haven't answered my questions or improved your initial question. What you are doing seems wrong from the start and looks like you aren't understanding Spring and try to work around it instead of work with the framework.

Comment: For instance öne of them get user rights and prepare authorizations, there are more than 1000 files. For instance some of them hve to start when system initialized get language params from db. There are many different purposes. Classic enterprise applications contains users, rights, duties etc. What iş the spring? You cant do everything ın service. Yes i have classic controllers_service_dao_generic but it iş not enough.

Comment: Now my problem is system autocommits everything since i switched to getcurrentsession even i did not set it true

Comment: As I stated you lack understanding of Spring or  dependency injection in general. The type of class doesn't matter a service is just a class like any another.

Comment: If you want to initialize data at startup use an `ApplicationListener` or `SmartInitializingSingelton` not a `@PostConstruct` method. Never the less you still don't need to construct your own context or use some ugly bridge or whatever it all works from within spring.

Comment: Ok but this is not solve my problem. What iş the default autocommit value? İ dıd not define true or false

Comment: If you use transactions it is false by default as you are controlling it. Also you are using MySQL make sure you use transactional tables (MyISAM isn't transactional). Also using the right component will solve your problem and setting up transaction also. However you still haven't improved your question with code, configuration etc so it is basically shooting in the wild.

Comment: I have applicationlistener as well. Same problem exist ın it. İ tried it. Autocommits itself.

Comment: Again post configuration, code...

Comment: İ am using MySQL. If i switch to open session i can manage transaction with begin or commit. If i switch to getcurrentsession it commits itself when any save or update happens.

Comment: Again post configuration, code...

Comment: Currently i am at cell phone and i am not able to post now.

Comment: I posted config file below. I trying to classic login. But if I do begin and commit transaction for login record I am getting error. If I dont use begin and commit transaction it goes fine and auto commit itself even i did not define autocommit true.

Comment: Improve your question, don't post it as an answer.

Comment: The problem is your configuration, remove `current_session_context_class` that breaks proper tx integration. Also your `hibernate.connection`, and `hibernate.c3p0` properties are useless due to the fact that you are injecting a `DataSource` which takes precedence over those settings.

Comment: I removed but it dış not changed, getting same error when i do begin and commit tx. It tries to do automatically again.

Comment: You shouldn't start a transaction yourself and as mentioned in a `@PostConstruct` method transactions don't work. Also make sure you have transactional tables. And post some code that isn't working (as requested multiple times).

Comment: I am not testing inside  @PostConstruct. I am testing with standard request. But it fails. Why I can not use getCurrentSession() with beginTransaction and commit().

Comment: In my application I need to save or update more than one entity at the same time. So I have to be sure that all done or none did not done. In order to success this, I have to do all in a beginTransaction and commit(). So I require to control transaction. Is there another why to achieve that?. Currently I am doing  it with openSession(). But for performance purposes I want to change it to getCurrentSession(). Am I at a wrong way?

Comment: You shouldn't as that interferes with springs tx management. Do you have `@Transactional` on your services? Post the code you ar trying (and your current hibernate configuration). You don't accidentally have a `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate.cfg.xml` in your classpath?

Comment: No you don't, you really seem to miss the point of spring managed transactions.

Comment: How do you post codes in this comment area? This is too short, I cant do it. You do not want me post at answer area

Comment: You should edit your question...

Comment: I could not do, it is very validated, I dont like post area. Very unuseless. I could not post all codes.